# Whatsapp latest apk with Whatsapp web menu option

Tags: android, whatsapp

I wanted to try today whatsapp web. It requires the latest apk, but i didn't see an update from the play store and I even downloaded the apk from the official whatsapp website. This version doesn't have the option "Whatsapp web" from the menu therefore i cannot scan the barcode.

Any idea how to get the latest apk ? Thanks

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, this question is not programming related. It would be much better if you asked it at https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm updating just now via the google play store. in the WHAT'S NEW section it mentioned "Introducing WhatsApp Web...". maybe you were too quick?

Comment: it seems the deployment was not for all at the same time